# iis memory limit app pool recycle kills executing requests

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that might grow in memory. I put a memory limit on the private bytes to recycle the app pool after 500m of memory usage. I noticed that my w3wp.exe process can get to 600megs when it decides to recycle and any currently executing client requests get a communication error.  Is there a way for iis to wait for requests to complete before recycling the process?

Comment: Are you running a farm or just a single WP?

Comment: Is this IIS6? IIS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recycling is killing an process when it reaches certain conditions, replacing it with another one.

In terrible-analogy-land, it's a bit like ensuring that the size of a balloon can only ever be one foot square by having pins positioned in a one-foot sphere - when the balloon hits the limit, it pops and you replace it with a new one.

Processes being recycled get up to {Shutdown Time Limit} to shut themselves down, from the point at which they're told to recycle.

If they can't finish their work in that time {90 second default}, that's it.

If you're using a WCF host with a persistent connection, then I think the answer's no; but the answer is also "pick larger limits". What you've described as your policy is: "I want my app to die when it hits 500MB." But the app itself doesn't know about that limit; it's just trying to grow as it needs to.

Load test your app without a limit; see what it gets to and what might indicate a leak; set limits at the point a leak is indicated.

Comment: thank you. this was the problem we just needed to give the shut-down time limit a little more time. However, it is too bad that it is not shutting down even before the shut-down time limit when the last request is finished. Its seems to finish the last request and just sit there until the shut-down time is finished.

Comment: That's generally an app hang. If you've not evaluated a hang dump before, short version is: take a memory dump of the target process using Task Manager of the same bitness, and use DebugDiag 1.2 to run a Crash/Hang analyzer over it. Or contact the app developer and have them do it.